# return false not working in form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

This is what I have and the form still goes to the page? I have been up since 1AM trying to fix it! Help!

```
function del_entry() {
    $('.delete_deal').submit(function() {
        var $g = $(this);                             
        $.ajax({
            url: $g.attr('action'),
            type: $g.attr('method'),
            data: $g.serializeArray(),
            cache: false,
        });
    }); 
    return false;
}; //end del_entry
```

And in my form:

```
<form name="delete_deal" action="inactivate_deal.php" class="delete_deal" method="post">
<a href="#" class="button" onClick="$('#deal_div_id').fadeOut(); del_entry();">Delete</a></form>
```

Comment: Can anyone help??? I've figure3d out how to make it return false and not go to the php page but now it won't execute the PHP script???

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `false` from the `submit()` function:

```
function del_entry(){
    $('.delete_deal').submit(function(){
        var $g = $(this);                             
                 $.ajax({
                 url: $g.attr('action'),
     type: $g.attr('method'),
             ta: $g.serializeArray(),
    cache: false,
           });
    return false;
    }); 
}; //end del_entry
```

You'll also need to prevent the browser's default behaviour kicking in for the anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `return false;` one line above... `;)`

Comment: @user1985009 Exactly... You expected something else?

Comment: Sorry - I want the POST info to be submitted in the form but via ajax so the user stays on the same page? (I am a noob with jQuery....sorry) Does that make sense?

Comment: @user1985009 Is the code you provided in your question exactly the one you're using? If yes, the attribute in the `ajax` function should be `data` and not only `ta`.

Comment: That was a typo - it says data.

Comment: So basically now it returns false but the POST data isn't reaching the php script (which I checked and it works). Ughhhhh...

Answer (score 0):

```
function del_entry(){
$('.delete_deal').submit(function(){
    var $g = $(this);                             
             $.ajax({
             url: $g.attr('action'),
     type: $g.attr('method'),
             ta: $g.serializeArray(),
    cache: false,
           });

         return false; // <----------------- ADD HERE

}); 

}; //end del_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're calling the `del_entry()` function from the HTML, you can simply do this:

```
function del_entry() 
{
    var $g = $('.delete_deal');

    $.ajax({
        url: $g.attr('action'),
        type: $g.attr('method'),
        ta: $g.serializeArray(),
        cache: false
    });
}
```